# Xamarin.Mac: Closed window is not reopened to click app icon in the dock

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I would like to be able to close all the windows once and then click on the icon in the Dock to make the window reopen again.

[image]

I was able to find the following code.

**`AppDelegate.cs`**

```cs
public override bool ApplicationShouldHandleReopen(NSApplication sender, bool hasVisibleWindows)
{
    if (hasVisibleWindows == false)
    {
      var mainWindow = new MainWindowController();
      mainWindow.ShowWindow(this);
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I can't find any file in the default project that defines `MainWindowController` as shown in the code above.

[image]

I thought I was supposed to use `ViewController`, and I've tried something, but it doesn't work as intended. What should I do?

The development environment is Visual Studio for Mac ver. 8.9.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, it works:

```
 public override bool ApplicationShouldHandleReopen(NSApplication sender, bool hasVisibleWindows)
 {
     if (!hasVisibleWindows)
     {
         foreach (var window in sender.Windows)
             window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
     }
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try (idk if this works in xamarin on mac but i had the same problem in winforms) creating new window, after what you can see in that hierarchy or solution explorer or whatever new window. Then create new instance and show it.

```
if (hasvisiblewindows == false)
        {
            NewWindow newWindow == new NewWindow();
            NewWindow.ShowWindow(this);
        }
```

I think this should help you.